# Find out who has written a message in a Facebook Conversation

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm dealing with bots in my app and a costumer ask me to auto detect the bot`s messages in a conversation.

When an app create a post I can see who wrote the post with: `me/posts?fields=admin_creator`

But when someone wrote a message in a conversation how can I see who wrote this message in the conversation API `me/conversations?fields=messages`

Edit: 
I need to know who answer the message through my page. It was me, a bot, an app or other person who have the permission to answer by my page.

Comment: Is Your app a mobile application or a website? What types od authentication do You support on Your page? What exactly do You mean by "page"?

Comment: I'm talking about API, not apps. Page means a Facebook Page

Comment: So, when You say "*I need to know who answer the message through my page*", You mean when somebody *commented* on a post on Your page? Or when someone made a *post* on Your page?

Comment: Somebody with access, use my page to reply a inbox message

Comment: Oh, so this is what You mean: "When a page profile (like [this](https://www.facebook.com/gary)) answers to someone in a conversation (inbox, i.e. messenger), how can I see who wrote as my page - me, bot, app, or another person?". I don't think that what You seek is possible, but please edit Your question to make it more clear. Good luck with finding the answer, or an alternative solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1

By reading the docs, I found this information that could help you:

> It's not possible to request a message by its individual message ID. Instead you should get the message as part of the thread it's a part of.

Note that the `message` object has `from` and `to` objects, so

Taken from the [Graph API Message docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/message).

### Solution #2

If that doesn't help You, I'm sure these two posts from the [chatbotsmagazine](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/) will:
In the post about a [Swell](https://medium.com/swell-wtf/swell-meets-bots-a0738daf493e) app, the poster asks the question:

> How could you identify the user? We have existing users in our
>   database who signed up with Facebook. There are two different user-ids
>   though, according to Facebook’s Docs:
>
> > (..) Ids are page-scoped. These ids differ from those returned from Facebook Login apps which are app-scoped. You must use ids retrieved from a Messenger integration for this page in order to function properly.

Then, they provided the answer to that question in this post:

[FB Messenger Bot  — How to Identify a User via Page- & App-Scoped User-ID’s](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/fb-messenger-bot-how-to-identify-a-user-via-page-app-scoped-user-ids-f95b807b7e46)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Casper, thanks for you effort, but it's is not the answer we need. The Solution #1, will show the name of my page and the name os the user. I need to know who answered the message through my page. Ex: I need to know if an app A or app B did thar answer in my page. The Solution #2 is about the user talking with me, I don't care about him.